# search and delete common text from two text files using dos

Tags: dos, findstr

just want to know the simplest solution to these:

how can I delete text in a.txt that are in b.txt using DOS
(a.txt & b.txt contains hundrends of text)

a.text

```
hfdjfhfjdfd
jjdhfjhkfkkf
jkfjjdfjdj
```

b.txt

```
dkhfkhf
hfdjfhfjdfd
jjdhfjhkfkkf
jkfjjdfjdj
jddkbskdjksk
bsdbvbdsdj
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually doing this in DOS or the command line of Windows? There is a VERY big difference.

Answer (score 0):

DOS is not a preferred way to do. This link has some details on how to remove data from a file. I am not an expert in DOS. The below information may be helpful to you.

http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/delete-text-in-txt-files-with-dos/12552.html

Below contents are from the website given above

```
If "in DOS" means Win XP/2K prompt, as I suspect, that can be achieved by For /F statement. Something as
For /F "tokens=1*" %%A in (Text_File) Do (
Echo horse %%B >> New_Text_File)
Move New_Text_File Text_File /Y
but you get a solution only if you can understand it.
```

Comment: thanks Joseph for your reply.i will just try to work around what i currently have using DOS.